# getting single row from table in sqlite android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, boolean

I start to learn android recently so I don't have much idea how can handle this problem.
I want to know how can I get single row from one of may table in database 
I read [androidhive database tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/) and try to write my code like sample code,but when I want to write 'getting single row' part I face with some problem.

**this is my model class**

```
public class UserMealUnit {
 int mealid;
 boolean breakfast;
 boolean lunch;
 float vegetables;
 public int getMealid() {
    return mealid;
}
public void setMealid(int mealid) {
    this.mealid = mealid;
}
public boolean isBreakfast() {
    return breakfast;
}
public void setBreakfast(boolean breakfast) {
    this.breakfast = breakfast;
}
public boolean isLunch() {
    return lunch;
}
public void setLunch(boolean lunch) {
    this.lunch = lunch;
}
    public float getVegetables() {
    return vegetables;
}
public void setVegetables(float vegetables) {
    this.vegetables = vegetables;
}
```

**this is my databaseAdapter codes `getting single row` part**

```
UserMealUnit getusermealunit(int mealid){
        SQLiteDatabase myDataBase = null;
        myDataBase = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor=myDataBase.query(TABLE_USERMEALUNIT, new String[] {TABLE_USERMEALUNIT_ID,
                TABLE_USERMEALUNIT_BREAKFAST,
                TABLE_USERMEALUNIT_LUNCH,
                TABLE_USERMEALUNIT_VEGETABLES,

                }, TABLE_USERMEALUNIT_ID + "=?",  new String[] { String.valueOf(mealid) },
                 null, null, null, null);
         if (cursor != null)
                cursor.moveToFirst();            
         UserMealUnit mealunit=new UserMealUnit(); 

        return mealunit;


    }
```

I have  problem in `UserMealUnit mealunit=new UserMealUnit();`part so I don't fill it yet.
as you can see I have boolean type, integer type and also float,in androidhive sample all column type is string,I cant get why he exactly parse them to integer type and what I have to do with this part in my code?
this is the part in androidhive

```
 Contact contact = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
```

Comment: Hi mimi, cursor.getString(0) It's KEY_ID, cursor.getString(1) is KEY_NAME and cursor.getString(2) is a KEY_PH_NO fields in Contact Table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no native *boolean data type* for SQLite. Please see [Datatypes doc for SQLite.](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) You can store int values like `0` for `false` and `1` for `true`.
Try like this

```
public UserMealUnit getusermealunit(int mealid) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_USERMEALUNIT + " WHERE "
            + TABLE_USERMEALUNIT_ID + " = " + mealid;

    Log.d(LOG, selectQuery);

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (c != null)
        c.moveToFirst();

    UserMealUnit mealunit = new UserMealUnit();
    mealunit.setMealid(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID)));//KEY_ID key for fetching id
    mealunit.setBreakfast((c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_BREAKFAST))));//KEY_BREAKFAST key for fetching isBreakfast
    mealunit.setLunch((c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_LUNCH))));//KEY_LUNCH key for fetching isLunch
    mealunit.setVegetables((c.getFloat(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_VEGETABLE))));//KEY_VEGETABLE key for fetching vegetables

    return mealunit;
}
```

**Model class**

```
public class UserMealUnit {

    int mealid;
    int breakfast;
    int lunch;
    float vegetables;

    public int getMealid() {
        return mealid;
    }
    public void setMealid(int mealid) {
        this.mealid = mealid;
    }
    public int getBreakfast() {
        return breakfast;
    }
    public void setBreakfast(int breakfast) {
        this.breakfast = breakfast;
    }
    public int getLunch() {
        return lunch;
    }
    public void setLunch(int lunch) {
        this.lunch = lunch;
    }
    public float getVegetables() {
        return vegetables;
    }
    public void setVegetables(float vegetables) {
        this.vegetables = vegetables;
    }
}
```

Query for creating `TABLE_USERMEALUNIT` table

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_USERMEALUNIT = "CREATE TABLE "
            + TABLE_USERMEALUNIT + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_BREAKFAST
            + " INTEGER,"+ KEY_LUNCH + " INTEGER," +  KEY_VEGETABLE + " REAL" + ")";
```

In `Activity` check the value of `lunch` or `breakfast` is equals to `1` like this

```
if(lunch == 1) {
   //lunch is int value fetched from db it means true do what ever you want to do
} else {
   //it means false do what ever you want to do
}
```

Comment: because of boolean type It gives me error what if I add !=0
`mealunit.setBreakfast((c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_BREAKFAST)))!=0);`?

Comment: There is no boolean type in SQLite database. Instead,I must save 0 as false and 1 as true. Thus to read your value so here KEY_BREAKFAST is boolean but we have getInt which get int type I use !=0 to solve this.

Comment: @mimi : yes, post create table query for `TABLE_USERMEALUNIT`

Comment: @mimi check the edited answer thats what I mean to say

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63079/discussion-between-mimi-and-kaushik).